# Optimize properties variables Spring Cloud

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-cloud

I started this architecture to practice and i found this "problem".
When i call microservices, need user and password of them. 
Same thing for zuul, need filter header for insert user and password.
I solved his problem inserting "hard coded" user and password. 
How can I improve the code in a cleaner way?

Git repo: https://github.com/alessandrolomanto/spring-cloud-microservices-with-security

Comment: The code works but I wanted some advice on how to improve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good practice to externalise any kind of sensitive information.

If I were you, I would use Environment Variables. This [answer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-sqs) explains how to fetch Env Variables in Java.

If you are running (or plan to run) on the Cloud, you can take a look into your provider's way to store parameters. AWS, for example, uses [Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html)

Yet another option would be to use environment variables in your .yml (or .properties) file as Spring [supports it out of the box](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). You could then Inject these properties via @Value in your application. This is the cleanest option in my opinion. Since you're already using Spring Cloud, you could then take a look into [Spring Cloud Config](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config), which is even nicer for your use case.

Other options would be to read a file during runtime, look up in a database, etc. You get the idea.

Comment: Spring Cloud Config builds on boots externalized configuration https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Just mentioned it in case the OP wants to externalise it in Config Server rather than env variables

Comment: I found the best solution using Spring Cloud Config Server. Thank you all for the support.